# Calendar type - Sharepoint Designer - Design view

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, calendar

[image]

Hi!

I am trying a add a header on a date on calendar so instead of just the date number it would have a text after. eg "15 - Meeting day" instead oj just "15"

I am able to edit this part from the developer tool but not on sharepoint designer as the design view is not showing for a calendar type (?) but would show on html type. Any advise?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How did you add the header on a date in calendar?

Did you add the custom code?

If you add the custom code, you could debug the code by F12 developer tool in IE.

[F12 Developer Tools.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772704(v=vs.85).aspx)